# XFRM IPsec over Geneve

Tags: linux-networking, ipsec, tunnel

I need to run IPsec over a Geneve tunnel (or GRETAP).  I can get the IPsec tunnel to work using public IPs as endpoints (so it's just IPsec) but not using private IPs on the Geneve link (so it's IPsec/Geneve.)

The Geneve tunnel is up and works:

```
[root@dd1215950359 /]# ip -d link show dev tun_gw2
6: tun_gw2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ca:9e:0e:f0:6b:9c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0 minmtu 68 maxmtu 65485 
    geneve id 102 remote 192.168.192.2 ttl 254 dstport 6081 noudpcsum udp6zerocsumrx addrgenmode eui64 numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535 
[root@dd1215950359 /]# ifconfig tun_gw2
tun_gw2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1450
        inet 192.168.12.2  netmask 255.255.255.254  broadcast 255.255.255.255
        ether ca:9e:0e:f0:6b:9c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 396  bytes 405632 (396.1 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 796  bytes 464646 (453.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The Geneve neighbor's IP is 192.168.12.3 and I can ping it.

I create the IPsec tunnel using this script.  If I use the same script but using the two GW's public IPs, it works.  But when I use the Geneve private IPs, the traffic bypasses the tunnel.

```
GW=1 # or 2, for the other side
GW1_PUBIP=192.168.160.5
GW2_PUBIP=192.168.192.2
PRIVNET=192.168.12 # address prefix on the Geneve link 
SPI=0x1234
MODE="mode tunnel"
PROTO="proto esp spi $SPI"
AUTHKEY=0x0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF
ENCKEY=0xFEDCBA9876543210FEDCBA9876543210
if [[ $GW == 1 ]]; then
    LOC_PUB_IP=$GW1_PUBIP REM_PUB_IP=$GW2_PUBIP LOC_PRI_IP=$PRIVNET.2 REM_PRI_IP=$PRIVNET.3
else
    LOC_PUB_IP=$GW2_PUBIP REM_PUB_IP=$GW1_PUBIP LOC_PRI_IP=$PRIVNET.3 REM_PRI_IP=$PRIVNET.2
fi  
PUBIP=$(ifconfig eth0 | grep inet | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f3)
if [[ $PUBIP == $LOC_PUB_IP ]]; then # trigger guard
    ip xfrm state flush; ip xfrm policy flush
    ip xfrm state add src $LOC_PRI_IP dst $REM_PRI_IP $PROTO $MODE auth sha256 $AUTHKEY enc aes $ENCKEY
    ip xfrm state add src $REM_PRI_IP dst $LOC_PRI_IP $PROTO $MODE auth sha256 $AUTHKEY enc aes $ENCKEY
    ip xfrm policy add dst 100.64/16 dir out tmpl src $LOC_PRI_IP dst $REM_PRI_IP $PROTO $MODE
    ip xfrm policy add src 100.64/16 dir in  tmpl src $REM_PRI_IP dst $LOC_PRI_IP $PROTO $MODE
    ip xfrm policy add src 100.64/16 dir fwd tmpl src $REM_PRI_IP dst $LOC_PRI_IP $PROTO $MODE
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

The encryption is meant to be on the tunnelling traffic, going between the public IP's.

Encryption always creates a tunnel and in this case you can combine it with the GRE header. If you wanted it on the inside IP addresses, you'd create another, separate, tunnel for which you'd need another set of private IP addresses.

In short, with encryption on the Geneve tunnel you're all set.